# how to handle the print dialog box close event in silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, printing, silverlight-5.0

I am new to Silverlight. I need to remove the `DatePicker` icon when printing. So I wrote this code to remove the icon when printing. It is working correctly if click on the print button in  print dialog box. But if I close the print dialog box date picker icon not coming up. I have to write the code in close event of print dialog box. I couldn't find the event of print dialog box.

This is the code for printing:

```
    private StackPanel Downloaded_Data(StackPanel Sp_Element)
    {
        foreach (UIElement ele in Sp_Element.Children)
        {
            if (ele is FirstPageTC)
            {
                if ((ele as FirstPageTC).Content is StackPanel)
                    Downloaded_Data((ele as FirstPageTC).Content as StackPanel);
                if ((ele as FirstPageTC).Content is Grid)
                    Download_Grid((ele as FirstPageTC).Content as Grid);
            }
            if (ele is Blank_Page)
            {
                if ((ele as Blank_Page).Content1 is StackPanel)
                    Downloaded_Data((ele as Blank_Page).Content1 as StackPanel);
                if ((ele as Blank_Page).Content1 is Grid)
                    Download_Grid((ele as Blank_Page).Content1 as Grid);
            }


            if (ele is DatePicker)
            {
                DatePicker s = ele as DatePicker;
                s.Style = App.Current.Resources["DateStyle"] as Style;
               // s.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 143, 188, 143));
            }

            if (ele is StackPanel)
            {
                Downloaded_Data(ele as StackPanel);
            }
            if (ele is Grid)
            {
                Download_Grid(ele as Grid);
            }
        }
        return Sp_Element;
    }

    public void Download_Grid(Grid grid_down)
    {
        foreach (UIElement ele in grid_down.Children)
        {
            if (ele is Border)
            {
                UIElement ele_b = (ele as Border).Child;
                if (ele_b is DatePicker)
                {
                    DatePicker s = ele_b as DatePicker;

                    s.Style = App.Current.Resources["DateStyle"] as Style;
                   // s.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 143, 188, 143));
                }

                //here
                if (ele_b is Grid)
                {
                    Download_Grid(ele_b as Grid);
                }
                if (ele_b is StackPanel)
                {
                    Downloaded_Data(ele_b as StackPanel);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Downloaded_Datepicker(StackPanel Sp_Element)
    {
        foreach (UIElement ele in Sp_Element.Children)
        {
            if (ele is FirstPageTC)
            {
                if ((ele as FirstPageTC).Content is StackPanel)
                    Downloaded_Datepicker((ele as FirstPageTC).Content as StackPanel);
                if ((ele as FirstPageTC).Content is Grid)
                    Download_GridDate((ele as FirstPageTC).Content as Grid);
            }
            if (ele is Blank_Page)
            {
                if ((ele as Blank_Page).Content1 is StackPanel)
                    Downloaded_Datepicker((ele as Blank_Page).Content1 as StackPanel);
                if ((ele as Blank_Page).Content1 is Grid)
                    Download_GridDate((ele as Blank_Page).Content1 as Grid);
            }


            if (ele is DatePicker)
            {
                DatePicker s = ele as DatePicker;

                s.Style = App.Current.Resources["DateNormal"] as Style;
            }

            if (ele is StackPanel)
            {
                Downloaded_Datepicker(ele as StackPanel);
            }
            if (ele is Grid)
            {
                Download_GridDate(ele as Grid);
            }
        }

    }

    public void Download_GridDate(Grid grid_down)
    {
        foreach (UIElement ele in grid_down.Children)
        {
            if (ele is Border)
            {
                UIElement ele_b = (ele as Border).Child;
                if (ele_b is DatePicker)
                {
                    DatePicker s = ele_b as DatePicker;
                    s.Style = App.Current.Resources["DateNormal"] as Style;

                }

                //here
                if (ele_b is Grid)
                {
                    Download_GridDate(ele_b as Grid);
                }
                if (ele_b is StackPanel)
                {
                    Downloaded_Datepicker(ele_b as StackPanel);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void PrintPage(StackPanel sp_Print)
    {
        foreach (UIElement sp_Element in sp_Print.Children)
        {
            if (sp_Element is StackPanel)
            {
                StackPanel printableSpnel=Downloaded_Data(sp_Element as StackPanel);
                //sp_Printing[count] = sp_Element as StackPanel;
                //count = count + 1;     
                sp_Printing[count] = printableSpnel;
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
       WithDatePickerIcon = sp_Print as StackPanel;
        print_Doc.PrintPage += new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(print_Doc_PrintPage);
        print_Doc.Print("REOSK Printing");
    }

    void print_Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        if (count == i)
        {                
            e.PageVisual = sp_Printing[i];
            e.HasMorePages = false;
            Downloaded_Datepicker(WithDatePickerIcon as StackPanel);
        }            
        else
        {      
            e.PageVisual = sp_Printing[i];                
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            i = i + 1;
            Downloaded_Datepicker(WithDatePickerIcon as StackPanel); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I fully understand your code, but there is one crucial thing wrong with it that probably is your problem:

You shouldn't start modifying any state of your program in the assumption printing starts (not even disabling the print button or indicating anything) unless the `BeginPrint` event is called on your `PrintDocument`. All you do there is then reverted to normal on the `EndPrint` event.

So most of your `PrintPage` method (shouldn't this be called `PrintPage*s*`?) should probably live in a handler listening on the `BeginPrint` event.

A working client of the printing api needs to listen to all three of those events. The printing starts with `BeginPrint`, not with a call to `Print`: The user can bail out of printing by clicking cancel, as you experienced.